# Alias for property of class in C# serialization

Tags: c#-4.0, serialization

Is there any way to set alias for property of class in C#.

Since property definition name could be too long, then I think alias is better in serialization, So the file size will be reduce.

Is this possible in c# ?

Please advise, Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try XmlType for types, XmlElement and XmlAttribute for properties.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmltype(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmltype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[XmlType("foo")]
class FooReallyLongName {

    public FooReallyLongName() {}

    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public BarReallyLongName { get; set; }
}
```

For Json try the counterparts here : http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm

or if you use Data Contract attributes, Newtonsoft.Json will also honor them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute

Excerpt from MSDN:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Customer", Namespace = "http://www.contoso.com")]
class Person : IExtensibleDataObject
{
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply, I am using Newtonsoft.Json for json serialization.